# Android disable navigationDrawer transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i'm using navigationDrawer sidebar in application and i can not disable transparent for that. after read any topic in this site i can not disable it or set Alpha

**activity_main:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.tsms.Activities.DashboardActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="ir.tsms.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111111"

        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_main:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.example.tab.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, ActionBar.TabListener {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Context context;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private int totalInboxSMS;
    public ReceivedSMS dataReceived;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getBaseContext();
        mNavigationDrawerFragment =
                (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        if (mViewPager != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    }
    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private int mSectionNumber = 0;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

            super.onAttach(activity);

            ((DashboardActivity) activity)
                    .onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }


}
```

I'm testing this ways:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
setDrawerShadow(Drawable shadowDrawable, int gravity)
setDrawerShadow(int resId, int gravity)
```

and

```
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111111"
```

but this ways does not work for me

Comment: What "transparent" do you want to remove?

Comment: @PedroOliveira http://rupload.ir/upload/h9i061f3hqt01adl9022.png

Comment: And you want it to make all black instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to show a black layout instead of that transparency you can try this:

Search on your NavigationDrawerFragment for the line:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

and replace it for

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.BLACK);
```